# Remove rows in dataframe by overlaping groups based on coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Seq Chrm start end  length score
A   C1   1     50   49 12
B   C1   3     55   52 12
C   C1   6     60   54 12
Cbis C1  6     60   54 11 
D   C1   70    120  50 12
E   C1   78    111  33 12
F   C2   350   400  50 12
A   C2   349   400  51 12
B   C2   450   500  50 12
```

And I would like, within each specific `Chrm`, to keep within each overlapping `start` and `end` the row with the longest `length` value AND the highest `Score` value.

For example in `C1`:

```
Seq    Chrm start end  length score
A      C1   1     50   49     12
B      C1   3     55   52     12
C      C1   6     60   54     12
Cbis   C1   6     60   54     11
D      C1   70    120  50     12
E      C1   78    111  33     12
```

Coordinates from `start` to `end` of **A,B,C,Cbis** together overlaps and **D** and **E** together overlaps.

In the **A,B,C,Cbis** group the longest are **C** and `Cbis` with `54, then I keep the one with the highest score which is **C**`  (12) `In the **D,E** group, the longest is **D** with`50`.
so I keep only the row **C** and **D** here.

If I do the same for other Chrm I should then get the following output:

```
Seq Chrm start end  length score
C   C1   6     60   54 12
D   C1   70    120  50 12
A   C2   349   400  51 12
B   C2   450   500  50 12
```

Here is the dataframe in dic format if it can help :

```
{'Seq': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'Cbis', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'F', 7: 'A', 8: 'B'}, 'Chrm': {0: 'C1', 1: 'C1', 2: 'C1', 3: 'C1', 4: 'C1', 5: 'C1', 6: 'C2', 7: 'C2', 8: 'C2'}, 'start': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 70, 5: 78, 6: 350, 7: 349, 8: 450}, 'end': {0: 50, 1: 55, 2: 60, 3: 60, 4: 120, 5: 111, 6: 400, 7: 400, 8: 500}, 'length': {0: 49, 1: 52, 2: 54, 3: 54, 4: 50, 5: 33, 6: 50, 7: 51, 8: 50}, 'score': {0: 12, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 11, 4: 12, 5: 12, 6: 12, 7: 12, 8: 12}}
```

---

Edit for **Corralien** :

If I used this table :

```
Seq Chrm start end     length score
A   C1   12414  14672  49     12
B   C1   12414  14741  52     12
C   C1   12414  14744  54     12
```

It does not class **A,B** and **C** in the same overlapping group...

```
{'Seq': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Chrm': {0: 'C1', 1: 'C1', 2: 'C1'}, 'start': {0: 12414, 1: 12414, 2: 12414}, 'end': {0: 14672, 1: 14741, 2: 14744}, 'length': {0: 49, 1: 52, 2: 54}, 'score': {0: 12, 1: 12, 2: 12}}
```

Comment: Where is the row D in your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create virtual groups and keep the best row (length, score) for each group:

Suppose this dataframe:

```
>>> df
     Seq Chrm  start    end  length  score
0      A   C1      1     50      49     12
1      B   C1      3     55      52     12
2      C   C1      6     60      54     12
3   Cbis   C1      6     60      54     11
4      D   C1     70    120      50     12
5      E   C1     78    111      33     12
6      F   C2    350    400      50     12
7      A   C2    349    400      51     12
8      B   C2    450    500      50     12
9      A   C1  12414  14672      49     12
10     B   C1  12414  14741      52     12
11     C   C1  12414  14744      54     12
```

Create groups:

```
is_overlapped = lambda x: x['start'] >= x['end'].shift(fill_value=-1)
df['group'] = df.sort_values(['Chrm', 'start', 'end']) \
                .groupby('Chrm').apply(is_overlapped).droplevel(0).cumsum()

out = df.sort_values(['group', 'length', 'score'], ascending=[True, False, False]) \
        .groupby(df['group']).head(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Seq Chrm  start    end  length  score  group
2    C   C1      6     60      54     12      1
4    D   C1     70    120      50     12      2
11   C   C1  12414  14744      54     12      3
7    A   C2    349    400      51     12      4
8    B   C2    450    500      50     12      5

# Groups
>>> df
     Seq Chrm  start    end  length  score  group
0      A   C1      1     50      49     12      1
1      B   C1      3     55      52     12      1
2      C   C1      6     60      54     12      1
3   Cbis   C1      6     60      54     11      1
4      D   C1     70    120      50     12      2
5      E   C1     78    111      33     12      2
6      F   C2    350    400      50     12      4
7      A   C2    349    400      51     12      4
8      B   C2    450    500      50     12      5
9      A   C1  12414  14672      49     12      3
10     B   C1  12414  14741      52     12      3
11     C   C1  12414  14744      54     12      3
```

You can drop the `group` column with `out.drop(columns='group')` but I left it to illustrate the virtual groups.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I added an edit to show you than in one example 3 row should be classed together but they are not with your code (A,B and C in the edit example at the bottom of the post)

Comment: The problem is probably because your dataframe is not sorted by `Chrm` columns at start. Maybe you have, C1, C1, C1, C2, C2, C1, C1, C3, ... As I use `values` (a numpy array without index), rows must be aligned, that is not the case here.

Comment: @chippycentra. I updated my answer. Does it solve your problem now? Keep in mind, for a same `Chrm` group, your dataframe should be sorted by `start` and `end` columns because we compare the current `start` with the previous `end` rows.

Comment: Hello, I would need the same code but by grouping two columns, I tried : ``` df['group'] = df.sort_values(['Chrm', 'start', 'end']) \
                .groupby(['Chrm','Seq']).apply(is_overlapped).droplevel(0).cumsum()``` But I get the following error message : ```TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index```. Any idea ?

Comment: @chippycentra. Use `as_index=False` as parameter of `groupby`: `df['group'] = df.sort_values(['Chrm', 'start', 'end']).groupby(['Chrm', 'Seq'], as_index=False).apply(is_overlapped).droplevel(0).cumsum()`